# Android emulator not allowing SD read or write

Tags: android, emulation, sd-card

Alright guys, here's what is going on.

I've spent the past two days trying to figure this out and I've had no luck.

**Symptom**:

My app downloads a file in an AsyncTask and stores it on the external SD Card. When running in the Android Emulator however, it fails to read or write to/from the SD Card.

The primary error I'm getting is a "read only" error. This can be "solved" by **remounting rootfs** and **chmoding /mnt/sdcard** but then I get errors saying no file exists and I am unable to make directories from with my app.

**What I've tried to do to fix it:**

Remount rootfs as rw and chmod 777 /mnt/

Result: File does not exist

Edit AVD conifg ini to add "hw.sdCard=yes.

**Result**: no change.

Any help is appreciated!

### Thanks!

Daniel

**EDIT: Add download/save code**

```
public class FileDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, File> {

    private static final String TAG = "FileDownloader";
    private int length = 0;

    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            String[] fileSplit = strings[0].split("/");
            String fileName = fileSplit[fileSplit.length - 1];
            File intoFile = new File(Updater.GetUpdateFolderPath(), fileName);

            if(!intoFile.exists()){
                intoFile.mkdirs();
                intoFile.createNewFile();
            }

            URL u = new URL(strings[0]);
            URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
            int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
            this.length = contentLength;

            DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

            int progress = 0;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
            while (stream.read(buffer) != -1) {
                progress++;
                publishProgress(progress);
            }
            stream.close();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(intoFile);
            fos.write(buffer);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

            return intoFile;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.d(TAG, values[0] + ":" + length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the permission in Manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Can you please share code snippet where you are trying to write to the storage?

Comment: I've added the AsyncTask class to the original post.

Comment: Did you check the path name? I am not sure what your Updater.GetUpdateFolderPath() is returning but to get the external sd card directory, you should use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

Comment: Updater.GetUpdateFolderPath() just returns Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/updates/";

Comment: the error I'm getting is "java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

It comes from here:
    File intoFile = new File(Updater.GetUpdateFolderPath(), fileName);
    
    if(!intoFile.exists()){
        intoFile.mkdirs();
        intoFile.createNewFile();
    }

Comment: Which emulator are you using? Are you sure there is a virtual SD card present in the emulator?

Comment: The stock android studio one